# MySQL GROUP BY not working as expected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, group-by

I have written a series of nested procedures which perform some pay calculations for employees. Throughout these procedures data is stored in temp tables.

Now the issue is some unexpected behaviour when I perform a GROUP BY on one of these temp tables. You can see an example of that step here:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4095/2

The expected behaviour is for that GROUP BY to output a list of `employeeid` and the corresponding aggregations. The sqlfiddle works as expected. However, what is happening is that I am getting a single row in the output with a blank `employeeid` and aggregated values for all rows. However, if I filter the data in a previous step to include a single unique `employeeid`, then I get a single row in the output (as expected) and with the `employeeid` column containing a value instead of being blank.

Initially, I thought this could be a memory issue since I am using lots of temporary tables (my understanding is that these are stored in memory) and wasn't dropping them. So I modified all of the procedures to drop any temporary tables as soon as they were no longer required. I am still facing the same issue. My tables are about 2000 rows and around 100 columns and the output of the GROUP BY should only be about 300 rows and 7 columns.

I'm going to continue thinking of different ways I can test this and will update if I find anything, but my question is: Does anyone know of anything that could potentially cause this type of behaviour?

EDIT: I've provided a simplified version in the sqlfiddle above, but here is the statement causing the problem (the table `temp_rawpaycalc` which is being GROUPED contains `shift_id`, `employeeid`, and all of the columns which are being aggregated. `employeeid` is in the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`, and `shift_id` is excluded from both.

`DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_topupaggr;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_topupaggr
SELECT employeeid,
    SUM(hoursworked) AS TotalHours,
    SUM(minguaranteepayamount) AS TotalMinGuarantee,
    (
        SUM(baseWagePayAmount) +
        SUM(basicAppPayAmount) +
        ...
        SUM(suppPayAmount)) AS TotalEarnings,
    SUM(reported_hoursworked) AS reported_TotalHours,
    SUM(reported_minGuaranteePayAmount) AS reported_TotalMinGuarantee,
    (
        SUM(reported_baseWagePayAmount) +
        SUM(reported_basicAppPayAmount) +
        ...
        SUM(reported_suppPayAmount)) AS reported_TotalEarnings
FROM temp_rawpaycalc 
GROUP BY employeeid;`

Comment: Temp tables aren't limited by RAM capacity. They work more - or - less like other tables, but with the expectation that they get dropped automatically when the connection closes.  It sounds to me like a temp table hasn't been populated correctly (the `employeeid` column is empty, maybe).

Comment: @O.Jones I've already verified that the temp table which is being grouped contains all of the necessary data, including the `employeeid` column. Furthermore, that doesn't explain why it works if there is a single employee, but not when there are multiple since all of the code is the same.

Comment: @BenA omitting an intermediate `GROUP BY employeeid` somewhere in your chain of data processing will end up with the remaining data processing having an effectively random single employeeid. If there is a single employee (specified/filtered in a WHERE clause presumably) the omission of the `group by` would not actually cause a problem, as the only data grouped is already limited to the specified id. Try a `SELECT DISTINCT employeeid FROM theTempTable`

Comment: @Uueerdo, as part of my troubleshooting, I am outputting the contents of the temptable on which I am grouping and I can see that it is correct (i.e. there are multiple employeeid values that the GROUP BY should be picking up). This step is the only step where I am performing a `GROUP BY employeeid`

Comment: Is it the only step you are using aggregation functions such as MIN, MAX, SUM, COUNT, GROUP_CONCAT, AVG, etc...?

Comment: @Uueerdo, do you mean if I am doing any aggregation in a previous step? I am not. The only aggregation being used on the problematic step is SUM(), and the only non-aggregated column in the step is `employeeid` which is being used in the GROUP BY

Comment: Oh...does the procedure in which the problematic query called have a parameter (or declared variable) called `employeeid`? (It could be grouping on the parameter/variable value, rather than the field value; it is almost always good practice to avoid ambiguous identifiers.)

Comment: @Uueerdo that was it! I did have `employeeid` as an input parameter and I've resolved this by explicitly specifying the column (i.e. `temp_rawpaycalc.employeeid`) in the SELECT and GROUP BY statements. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedure parameters seem to get higher priority than tables' field names inside stored procedures; if there are ambiguous identifiers for field names and parameters in queries used in stored procedures, it can cause hard to identify problems.

Solution: always qualify such field names (good practice anyway) and/or do not use identifiers for parameters on stored procedures that might conflict with field names in tables the procedure references (also a good practice for general readability even if field names are always qualified).